# x86 assembly-esp and ebp default segment

Tags: assembly, x86

I know that the default segment for `ebp` and `esp` is the stack segment, but I am confused because as mentioned in literature, every register, including `ebp` and `esp` can be used as pointers to variables in data segment, and it works without segment override for these two registers.
Thanks if any one can help

Comment: It only works without override if `ss==ds` which is the usual case under everyday protected mode operating systems (e.g. linux, windows, macos)

Comment: so for use in stack frames, every register other than ebp can be used, when ss=ds?? @Jester

Comment: Note that if you are using the instructions `MOVS`, `SCAS`, `CMPS` or `STOS`, then the `ES` segment is associated with `EDI` by default (quite often the same as `DS`).

Comment: @WeatherVane `INS` also solely uses the `ES` segment register.

Comment: @SepRoland yes I know thank you but direct I/O is not usually relevant to an application so I left it out.

Comment: Note that that `ES` associated with `EDI` in "string" (`movs`, ...) instructions can't be overridden, while the `DS` associated with `ESI` can, so `es:lodsb` will load `al` with byte from `[es:esi]`. And yes, when `ss == ds`, you can use also other registers to address the stack without prefixing the instructions with `ss:`. The default segment register affects the CPU, where it will look for the value (`ds` vs `ss`), but as it will get the same value, the final physical address will be from same segment in both cases. These things were super important in 16b real mode, now almost irrelevant.